# How to trigger Cloudwatch Alarms from Coudwatch Insights Queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, cloudwatch-alarms

How do I trigger `Cloudwatch Alarm` based on output of `Cloudwatch Insights` queries?

```sql
SELECT CPUUtilization
  FROM SCHEMA("AWS/EC2", InstanceId) 
  WHERE CPUUtilization > 80
  GROUP BY InstanceId
```

For every record in the above query output, I would like to raise an alarm.

What's the best way to do this?